# How to remove duplicate screen_names on twitter data using rtweet in R-studios

Tags: r, rtweet

I'm learning how to use R studios and I'm doing a bit of social media analysis on twitter. What I'm trying to do is to extract 'verified' and 'non verified' users from the data. I've managed to separate the variables but I've noticed that there are several duplicate user_ids and screen names. Not sure why this is the case. So my question is, how would I remove these duplicates?
[image: Pic 1]

Comment: Do you mean `df1 <- df[!duplicated(df$user_id),]` ?

Comment: Thank you!! Just tried this and it worked!! Any idea why it duplicates the users??